# Is every ring of cardinality 2 isomorphic to $Z_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My thought process was that for cardinality different than $1$, identities in multiplication and addition are different, so they constitute the entire group. Does this show it has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$? I think no, because we can define addition in some strange manner, such that

$0+0=0;
1+0=1;
1+1=1$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your $+$ does not define a group because $\forall x,\, 1+x\ne 0$.

Comment: Sorry, why does it not define a group?

Comment: In other words, $1$ does not have an additive inverse.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (sometimes denoted $\mathbb{Z}_2$) rather than $Z_n$?

Comment: You can (indeed, must) define the addition as for ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$, but you can define the multiplication by $ab=0$ for all $a,b$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_ring#Enumeration for a discussion of the number of rings with $n$ elements.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That raises the question of whether the identically-$0$ product is ok for this case, since the author mentions explicitly the multiplicative unit: we could argue that here "ring" is ring with $1$.

Comment: @Sassatelli, the author also gives an addition without additive inverses, so I wasn't going to guess about units. If one insists on a multiplicative unit, then for prime $p$,  every ring with $p$ elements is isomorphic to ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$. Rings with unity are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A037291